# C Program isn't returning anything

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I wrote a C program to sort an array, but the program isn't returning anything -- it just runs and stuck there as if it is waiting for input. Below is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

bool unsorted(int ar[],int x){
    int c;
    for(int i=1;i<=x;i++){
        if(ar[0]>ar[i]){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}   

void sort(int arr[],int s){
    int h,b;
    while(unsorted(arr,s)){
        h=arr[0];
        for(int i=0;i<=s;i++){
            if(arr[i]>h){
                b=arr[i];
                arr[i]=h;
                h=b;
            }
        }
     }
     for(int i=0;i<=s;i++){
       printf("%d",arr[i]);
    }
}
int main(){
    int arr[3]={ 2,1,3 };
    sort(arr,3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: side note : thts c++ not c edit the tag

Comment: You are exceeding the bounds of the array with loops like `for(int i=0; i<=s; i++)` which shold be `for(int i=0; i<s; i++)`.

Comment: `if(ar[0]>ar[i])` was this intented to be `if(ar[i-1]>ar[i])` instead?

Comment: You should start using a debugger. It can show you the execution flow in your program and you can compare actual values of variables with your expected values. You might find out that your function `unsorted` and the `for` loop in `sort` are not really aligned wrt what "sorted" means.

Comment: no,this function is to just check whether array is sorted.

Comment: can you please suggest me a debugger

Comment: Which order is regardet to be sorted? Ascending or descending?

Comment: I use GDB as debugger. It depends on your compiler and environment

Comment: in ascending order

Answer (score 1):

Your function `unsorted` returns `true` if the first element ist not the smallest. It is not checked whether any other 2 elements are in wrong order. This will cause wrong results but is not the reason for current problem.

In your sorting loop you check if any element is larger than the first and then swaps them.
This means ascending order is changed to descending.
This will cause `unsorted` function to return `true` all the time and your loop never terminates.

To fix it change condition:

```
void sort(int arr[],int s) {
    int h,b;
    while (unsorted(arr,s)) {
        h=arr[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < s; i++) {
            if (h > arr[i]) {
                b = arr[i];
                arr[i] = h;
                h = b;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i < s; i++) {
            printf("%d",arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Also the index range was fixed.

This should at least make your loop terminate.
It will not produce a sorted list as you terminate too early.

First of all your `unsorted` function needs some update:

```
bool unsorted(int ar[], int x) {
    int c;
    for (int i = 1; i < x; i++) {
        if (ar[i-1] > ar[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This should also return `true` if first element is lowest but others don't fit like `{1, 4, 3, 6}`. Also note the fixed index range.

You need to apply a similar fix to the sorting part to handle out-of-order values in the elements after the first one.